# Keyboard and/or mouse profiles similar to NetSetMan?

Tags: mouse, keyboard, profiling

[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware) lets you configure and recall presets/profiles for various network settings, presumably by adapter and location (I'm still learning how to use it).

I would like a similar software for keyboard and mouse settings (2 different use cases, but might be in the same software).

1. I have a laptop that does not have a number pad, and when I plug in an external keyboard and attempt to use the number pad, I get thrown off my game*, and then have to manually turn on numlock.  When I detach the external keyboard, I then get thrown off my game* and have to manually disable numlock for the builtin keyboard.  I would like a way to automate this based on the keyboard(s) that are plugged in or active.  This also gets annoying when you have to fight with VM software that's turning the numlock on and off, which is why I think this can be done.
2. I have an older mouse (Intellimouse Explorer 3)that when plugged in to my new laptop, disagrees about the DPI setting.  The older mouse requires me to modify the mouse cursor speed setting in Windows (almost maxing it out), while a newer mouse (Microsoft Arc mouse Bluetooth) moves just fine at the default setting (in the middle).  I would like a profile for each mouse and to either manually or automatically move between the two.

I think the settings are somewhat related, so maybe there's one piece of software that can fulfill both roles.  If not, 2 softwares is OK too.

**Must haves**

- Modify the above settings
- Configurable settings (automatic, recall toggle, etc)
- Work in Windows 7, 10
- Work with all (practically) peripherals

**Nice to haves**

- Free or low cost (less than $10)
- Compatible with the Windows 10 charm bar for ease of access

I have not been able to find something close.  I can imagine that gaming related software might have something to offer, but I suspect it would be hardware specific.

*"Thrown off my game" being a figurative expression, not a literal one.  Aka "derailed" and synonymous with interrupted.  I'm ***not*** referring to actual PC games.